# Getting filename from Logger object in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need a way to retrieve the "filename" that a python 3.4.2 Logger object "mylogger" points to.

Comment: did you try using https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in range(0, len(mylogger.handlers)):
    try:
        print(mylogger.handlers[i].baseFilename)
    except AttributeError:
        print('no to file')
```

`mylogger` can send logs to several files as well to stdout or to an email address